# How to make an item clickable before the page is ready?

Tags: jquery, dynamics-crm, userscripts

We have a Microsoft CRM Dynamics online database.
I have written a userscript for GreaseMonkey in Firefox (uses jquery) that fetches an item's `id` from the query parameters and displays it in a little area of the top toolbar.

The script fetches the id immediately and displays it. However, I have to wait for the page to load before I can click on the area and copy the id.

What can I do to make it so I can click on the area *before* the page is finished loading?  I am *not* using `document.ready` because I don't want to wait.

Here is where I insert the id into the toolbar area:

```
$('#crmRibbonManager').append("<div id='arxbar'><div id='arxidinfo'><span class='arxnote'>RecordID=&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><input type='text' id='arxid' value='" + itemid + "'/></div></div>");
```

This is the code that selects the id and copies it to the clipboard for me:

```
$('#arxid').focus(function(){ 
    $('#arxid').select(); 
    document.execCommand('copy');
}).mouseup( function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: I'm thinking this isn't possible. The way to do it properly would be to put that script in the head or immediately inside the body tag to get it to execute before any of the DOM or other scripts are parsed. However, since you're using a User Script for this, I would imagine that they aren't added to the DOM until the very bottom, and might even automatically be wrapped in code to wait until the page is ready. I could easily be wrong about that, but this behavior is making me think that is the case.

Comment: But my id text shows right from the start - I just can't click until the page is loaded.

Comment: So that `.append()` executes immediately, but your `.focus()` event won't trigger until after the page gets loaded?

Comment: That's how it seems to me.  After the page is loaded, when I click on it then it selects all the text by itself.  Before the page is finished loading when I click on it nothing happens.

Comment: Actually, before the page is finished loading, when I hover over the box, the cursor doesn't even change to the text-bar - it stays an arrow.  But once the page is loaded *then* it turns to a text-bar and is clickable.

Comment: It sounds like something else is occurring with the element then. Perhaps checking the HTML that's sent to the browser (view source) can help point you to what you have originally versus what is there after the page is finished loading. It could be that turning your `.focus()` event into a delegate event _might_ fix your problem.

Comment: For testing purpose, could you try binding click event instead of focus? Just wanna see whether there is something fishy with focus.

Comment: I started with click, in fact.  Same problem.  I can't get a hand cursor until the page is loaded.  I'm sure CRM is preventing the interaction on some level.

Comment: Sounds like they might be putting an invisible div over the page while it's loading to prevent clicking. In Chrome, if you try to right click your area and select 'inspect' while the page is loading, you would see the inspector select the blocking element if it exists.